# IIS 7.5 URL Rewrite - replace domain

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26840890/i-need-to-change-domain-with-iis-7-5-url-rewrite (unanswered yet)

I have the following URLs

```
www.myolddomain.com/somefolder-a
www.myolddomain.com/somefolder-b
www.myolddomain.com/somefolder-c
...
```

I want one rule to redirect every request incoming containing `myolddomain.com/somefolder` to `www.mynewdomain.com/somefolder` with above suffix such as `-a`.

My rule so far looks like this:

```
<rule name="Redirect from old domain" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)myolddomain.com/somefolder(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.mynewdomain.com/somefolder{R:2}" />
</rule>
```

This rule has no effect whatsoever.

*Did I make a mistake here already?
Or could requests be redirected at some other place before IIS?*

According to the firewall admin no redirects take place at the firewall. Could it be anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Through further trial and error I found a solution:

```
<rule name="Redirect from old domain" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="myolddomain.com" />
        <add input="{HTTP_URL}" pattern="/somefolder(.*)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.mynewdomain.com/somefolder{C:1}" />
</rule>
```

For curiousity, how is the match on the rule level supposed to work? No matter what I put there, as soon as it is anything else than .* the rule is ignored.

Hint to others: don't fall into the trap of thinking that server variables like "HTTP_URL" actually contain the URL - they do NOT. Best way to figure out what is really in which variable is a sample page like this (copied from the web - I apologize for having lost the link):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Server Variables</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Server Variable</th>
<th>Value</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>HTTP_URL: </td>
<td><%= Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_URL"] %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Replace above server variable to retrieve different variables</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```